# Button Text in Centre for iphone/ios

Tags: javascript, html, css

Been trying with a button text to place in centre of it but i dont know wat might be the problem as the text is always away from centre of button.

```
<marquee behavior="alternate"><button id="nine" type="button" style="-webkit-appearance:button;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;width:100px;height:100px;border: 2px solid black;font: bolder 50px courier;text-align:center" >9</button></marquee>

<marquee behavior="alternate"><button id="six" type="button" style="-webkit-appearance:button;-webkit-border-radius: 50%;width:100px;height:100px;border: 2px solid black;font: bolder 50px courier;text-align:center" >6</button></marquee>
```

Comment: I've just ran this with JSFiddle and it seems just fine to me, can you add a screenshot of the problem please?

Comment: it ran well on fiddle but on iphone button text-9,6 away from centre of circle. i dont have rating to post an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have no trouble in keeping the text in the center of the buttons, just tried it in chrome and IE. Not entirely sure what the problem is.